# data scraping return a blank for the following link

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have a requirement to scrape data from the following link http:// 164. 100. 47. 132 /LssNew/members/homepage.aspx?mpsno=4589 (details Constituency; Party Name; Present Address and Permanent Address)

The tags I found to be too generic in nature to form bases of scraping this data. Could someone please guide me on getting this data?

Sample I am working with:

```
import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http:// 164. 100. 47. 132/LssNew/members/homepage.aspx?mpsno=4433")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
##regex = '<span id="ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_Homepagetest1_Label4">(.+?)</span>'
regex = '<span class="style13">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
print htmltext
print pattern
lsmember = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print lsmember[0:100]
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and what didn't work in your solution?

Comment: import urllib
import re

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/members/homepage.aspx?mpsno=4433")
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
##regex = '<span id="ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_Homepagetest1_Label4">(.+?)</span>'
regex = '<span class="style13">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
print htmltext
print pattern
lsmember = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print lsmember[0:100]

Comment: Please edit the question, as you might have noticed the comments don't really format code well.

Comment: Perhaps you could be better served using something like [http://scrapy.org](http://scrapy.org) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to aid in extracting the proper data. Regex is a bit buggy when it comes to HTML and Scrapy and BeautifulSoup support DOM parsers which make it somewhat easier. (it will require more boilerplate though)

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use your own script for scrap this website?

There is a service that creates API REST from scrapping a web, and usually find easily your own pattern.

This services is https://www.kimonolabs.com/

It's free, but it's a third part service, so I don't know if you must use your own script or it's great for you. Some websites are difficult to scrap, and like this case, the info you need is inside a table without classes.

This services also supports a parameter in the URL so you can create one for many possible html files.